# Statistical testing for multiple columns from a dataframe

Tags: r

For the data frame below I want to perform kolmogorov-smirnov tests for multiple columns. Column ID is the record ID, A-D are factors consisting of 2 levels ('Other' and A,B,C,D respectively. My test variable is in column E.

Now I would like to perform 4 KS tests:

- Distributions of E for column A (A vs O)
- Distributions of E for column B (B vs O)
- Distributions of E for column C (C vs O)
- Distributions of E for column A (D vs O)

In reality, I have 80 columns, so I'm looking for a way to perform these 80 tests 'Simultaneously'

```
  ID A B C D  E
1  1 O B C O  1
2  2 O O O O  3
3  3 O O O D  2
4  4 A O C D  7
5  5 A B O O 12
6  6 O O O O  4
7  7 O B O O  8
```

Comment: what have your tried so far ? and where are you stuck ?

Comment: I'm stuck at creating the vectors that I need for KS testing. As I see it, I need 2 vectors containing values from colums E for each of the columns A-D. Once I have those, I would like to run the KS test on all paired vectors

Comment: I'm very unsure of what I'll say, but giving a try anyway: is `test[2:5] <- lapply(test[2:5],as.factor); lapply(test[2:5],ks.test,y=test$E)` what you're after ? (test is a dataframe from your example)

Comment: Thanks so far, I think that's almost what I'm looking for. Except for the fact that the returned p-values in my actual dataset are too low (e.g. 2.2e-16 where it should be around 0.09). Maybe it has something to do with the factors??? It seems to return 2.2e-16 for all tests

Comment: To be honest, I'm not a statistician, so I can't tell if the results are good or not here, I just can help in the method to work on the dataframe itself :)

Comment: probably more like `lapply(names(df)[2:5], function(crit, distrib) ks.test(df[df[, crit]==crit, distrib, df[df[, crit]!=crit, distrib), distrib=df$E)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this solves your problem:

```
dat <- read.table("path/data.txt") # your data imported into my session. 

cols <- c("A", "B", "C", "D") #these are the your columnss with categories. We leave the others out.
E <- dat$E # but save the E variable
lapply(cols, function(i){ # Evaluate E at each level of each column
  x <- factor(dat[,i])
  a <- E[x == levels(x)[1]]
  b <- E[x == levels(x)[2]]
  ks.test(a, b)
  }) #you get a list with the results for each column
```

Comment: why not just loop over `cols` rather than `1:ncol(dat[, cols])` which could already be simplified in `1:length(cols)` ?... then you could just do `x <- dat[, ind]` and `x==ind`...

Comment: `lapply(cols,function(i) { x <- dat[,i]; a <- dat$E[x == levels(x)[1]]; b<- test$E[x == levels(x)[2]]; ks.test(a,b) })`  does the job indeed.

Comment: true, it can be simplified

Comment: you need to make sure the column is a factor if you want to use `levels(x)`, or define `x` with `factor(dat[, i])`

Comment: Everyone, thanks for your comments! This saves me a lot of time......and frustrations ;-)