# Create multiple vectors from data frame for testing

Tags: r, vector

I would like to create multiple vectors from my data frame and subsequently perform a test on these (paired) vectors. In the data frame below A is a factor with 2 levels, B is a factor with 5 levels and C is a numerical variable.

So, for each value of VAR2 I would like to test the values of VAR3 for X vs Y (VAR1). In the example below: For A (VAR2) I need a vector (1,2) for X and (6,12) for Y (and vectors for the other factors in VAR2 as well). I think I need to use a custom made function (since my actual dataset has around 80 unique values for VAR2, but I don't no how to make it.

```
   ID VAR1 VAR2 VAR3
1   1    X    A    1
2   2    Y    B    4
3   3    Y    C    3
4   4    Y    A    6
5   5    Y    D    3
6   6    X    A    2
7   7    X    B    6
8   8    Y    C    9
9   9    Y    A   12
10 10    Y    E    2
```

Comment: Could you add the desired output for the function?

Comment: Ideally, the output would be the result of a test (e.g. kolmogorov-smirnov) for each unique value of VAR2, testing X vs Y from VAR1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this produce the result you want?

```
data = fread(' ID VAR1 VAR2 VAR3
               1    X    A    1
               2    Y    B    4
               3    Y    C    3
               4    Y    A    6
               5    Y    D    3
               6    X    A    2
               7    X    B    6
               8    Y    C    9
               9    Y    A   12
               10    Y    E    2')


data$VAR2=as.factor(data$VAR2)
factors= levels(data$VAR2)
lapply(factors,function(i){
   x_values=data[VAR2==i & VAR1=="X"]$VAR3
   y_values=data[VAR2==i & VAR1=="Y"]$VAR3
   ks.test(x_values, y_values)
})
```

I think this matches the answer you suggested.

Comment: This results in the correct combinations, but now each cell has comma separated values and I'm not sure how to perform a test on this

Comment: For a similar issue (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346499/statistical-testing-for-multiple-columns-from-a-dataframe) someone suggested the following:                                                                                               lapply(cols, function(i){ # Evaluate E at each level of each column
  x <- factor(dat[,i])
  a <- E[x == levels(x)[1]]
  b <- E[x == levels(x)[2]]
  ks.test(a, b)     
  })      Something like that would be ideal

Comment: Seems exactly what I'm looking for! Only thing now is that I get an error in my actual data that objects VAR1 (and also VAR2) is not found.

Comment: Check that your data has the column names that you had in your original post (so ID VAR1 VAR2 VAR3) (see names(data)) and make sure it is a data table (use setDT(data) )

Comment: Names were correct, but setDT did the job. Thanks a lot!!